# Spring-boot-maven-plugin doesn´t deploy to one of two artifact repositories

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jenkins

I have two artifact repositories, one for snapshots and other for releases. The older project uses maven-release-plugin and successfuly deploys to both repositories depending on the parameters passed.

But I have a Spring Boot application which uses spring-boot-maven-plugin, and with the same configuration it only deploys to my snapshot repository, even though I pass release as parameter. I´d also like for it to remove -SNAPSHOT of the resulting artifact.

I´m using Jenkis for build and deployment.

Can anyone shed a light on this? I´ve researched but came out empty. Please ask me if you need any more information. Thanks in advance!

These are the parameters in my 'Goals and options' section on jenkins for both applications.

```
deploy -P release --batch-mode release:prepare release:perform -DscmCommentPrefix=RELEASE -DignoreSnapshots=true -D https.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Working legacy pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>10.28.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.scm.id>git-myapp</project.scm.id>
    <!-- Sonar properties-->
    <sonar.java.source>7</sonar.java.source>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <version.cdi-unit>3.1.5-SNAPSHOT</version.cdi-unit>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ext-release-local</id>
        <url>http://myapp.com:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>ext-snapshot-local</id>
        <url>http://myapp.com:8081/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>       
</repositories> 


<scm>
    <url>scm:git:https://git.myapp.com:1443/myuser/myapp.git</url>
    <connection>scm:git:https://git.myapp.com:1443/myuser/myapp.git</connection>
    <tag>myapp-10.28.0</tag>
</scm>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>ext-release-local</id>
        <name>ext-release-local</name>
        <url>http://myapp.com:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ext-snapshot-local</id>
        <name>ext-snapshot-local</name>
        <url>http://myapp.com:8081/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>agent-for-ut</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <append>true</append>
                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>agent-for-it</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <append>true</append>
                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>perform</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <pomFileName>myapp/pom.xml</pomFileName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Non-working pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>qrcode-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>qrcode-api</name>
<description>QRCode Processing API</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
        <artifactId>ghostdriver</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<scm>
    <url>scm:git:https://git.myapp.com:1443/myapp/qrcode-api.git</url>
    <connection>scm:git:https://git.myapp.com:1443/myapp/qrcode-api.git</connection>
    <tag>qrcode-1.0.0</tag>
</scm>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>ext-release-local</id>
        <url>http://myapp.com:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>ext-snapshot-local</id>
        <url>http://myapp.com:8081/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>ext-release-local</id>
        <name>ext-release-local</name>
        <url>http://myapp.com:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ext-snapshot-local</id>
        <name>ext-snapshot-local</name>
        <url>http://myapp.com:8081/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your non-interactive release, it appears that you're [missing a few properties](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html) to actually ensure that the version is incremented.

```
mvn --batch-mode -Dtag=my-proj-1.2 release:prepare \
             -DreleaseVersion=1.2 \
             -DdevelopmentVersion=2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Those -D flags are important; they set the release version (thus removing the -SNAPSHOT from your version) and set the new release version.

Comment: Thanks, but can´t maven read the version in pom.xml for the release version? Does this work for the Spring Boot plugin?

Comment: Maven *is* reading the version in your POM, which is why it's not deploying to a release repository given that the version in your POM is still a snapshot.  The release plugin has the power (if you grant it) to modify the version in your POM which should get you past this issue.

Comment: Ok, in fact in other company I worked at we had to specify version numbers for the CI tool, I guess it should set these parameters. What I still don´t understand is why the behaviour is different between these two plugins... I guess when you pass the -P release --batch-mode release:prepare release:perform arguments, it should override the snapshot indication in the pom.xml, shouldn´t it?

Comment: Effectively, yes.  The release plugin stages the changes and writes a new version to the stage, commits tags and builds *it*, and deploys it to your artifact repository, then it creates a *new* version based on your development version, commits and builds it.